# Redis: possible to expire an element in an array or sorted set?

Tags: caching, redis

Is it currently only possible to expire an entire key/value pair? What if I want to add values to a List type structure and have them get auto removed 1 hour after insertion. Is that currently possible, or would it require running a cron job to do the purging manually?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

> Is it currently only possible to expire an entire key/value pair?

As far as I know, and also according to [key](http://redis.io/commands#generic) commands and document about [expiration](http://redis.io/commands/expire), currently you can set expiration only to specific key and not to it's underlying data structure. However there is a [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/redis-db/browse_thread/thread/ad75cc08b364352b) on google groups about this functionality with outlined alternative solutions.

Comment: Any idea as of now July 2016 they have supported this in there newer version?

Comment: @KamranShahid got anything on this??

Comment: Nop Prakash not yet.

Comment: Is this answer still relevant after 8 years?

Comment: Yep, element expiration in nested data structures is not supported by Redis.

Answer (score 139):

There is a common pattern that solves this problem quite well.

Use sorted sets, and use a timestamp as the score. It's then trivial to delete items by score range, which could be done periodically, or only on every write, with reads always ignoring the out of range elements, by reading only a range of scores.

More here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/rXXMCLNkNSs

Comment: Nice solution, but I wish redis supported this properly.  It's a common requirement and shouldn't require complex workarounds.

Comment: I dunno, I'm really happy they stick to their guns - expanding the feature set in ways they don't want or don't plan means making design sacrifices.  Building additional functionality on top sounds like the perfect solution, and leaves Redis to do what it does, excellently

Comment: redis is perfect as it is - simple, clean design and predictable behavior which results in more than excellent preformance

Comment: Wonderful solution, we were also able to use a simple fifo list where we kept a list and simply took the first 5 elements, and when the list grew larger than 5+N depending on scalability, we delete the key and start over. Simple, easy, and exactly how Redis algorithms should be. This algorithm gives our reporting system plenty of time to query the list and see what devices users login with. Agree with @KierenJohnstone , Redis is designed to create architecture around it and is perfect just how it is.

Comment: @let4be given that redis already supports expire for keys, I agree with UpTheCreek, it would be nice to extend the expire command to support sorted sets. That would not overcomplicate redis design nor degrade performace

Answer (score 5):

I came upon a different method of handling this, don't know if it's helpful to any of you,but here goes:

The hash and the sorted set are linked by a guid.

1. I have a hash that is set to expire in 'x' seconds
2. I have a sorted set that is used for ranged queries
3. The data for both is added in a transaction, so if one fails, they both fail.
4. Upon a ranged query, use 'EXISTS' to see if the hashed value exists as the results are iterated over
5. If it does not exist, it has expired, so delete the item from the sorted set

Answer (score -1):

What about creating two seperate sorted sets?

Main sorted set which is `key = value`.

Expire sorted set which is `key = expire_timestamp`.
If you only want to expire a single score you can set as `key:unique_id = expire_timestamp`.

With mercy of zrangebyscore we can get expired keys. Then all we need to do is check periodically and `zrem`.
If you only want to expire a single score: `​zincrby -1`.