# Redis: Expire set element - members must be unique

Tags: redis, unique, sortedset

I have the requirement to store integer values and expire them by time. I must also be able to get all values easily.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577923/redis-possible-to-expire-an-element-in-an-array-or-sorted-set) post, a good solution is to use sorted sets where the score is the unix time at which an expire will happen. So with the format `key score member`:

```
ZADD foo [timestamp] 25
```

The docs state that sorted set members are unique and scores may be repeated, so in my use case there may be multiple duplicate members.

How would I make the member unique? I could store the timestamp once again as part of the member however this seems inefficient and for my use case there could be a possibility of a duplicate.

I could store the timestamp as milliseconds as part of the member to reduce the likelihood of a duplicate.

Can anyone advise on best practice?

Comment: Combining the member's value with a timestamp is the common way to deal with this - you're on the right track

Comment: @ItamarHaber - OK, thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully helpful for others, I combined the timestamp with the value:

```
ZADD foo timestamp timestamp:value
```

Comment: lets say i want to replace data with the same timestamp kinda like an update, would this work