# Redis strings as special arrays

Tags: redis

I'm creating a system of events which are to be retrieved through AJAX by clients (webbrowsers). For events store I want to use Redis only.

I learnt about some nice features in Redis, such as **EXPIRE** - a command allowing to do a kind of Garbage Collection work automatically, so that there's no need to implement an equivalent of it yourself (provided that the solution would be as efficient as Redis one). Indeed, very nice, and I'm going to use it.

But then, I stumbled upon a problem how to store a related to a Redis' **Strings** data-type unix time stamp number. This number should be used for:

- ordering the whole "set" of data - all events
- and foremost, for getting only events records (Strings) above the given number (i.e. > given_time)

So in brief, I wanted to have something like a **SCORE** functionality related to Strings, but not necesserily in a way that it is used with **Sorted Sets** in Redis. And I didn't like the solution proposed here to use in fact kind of Sets: [Redis: possible to expire an element in an array or sorted set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577923/redis-possible-to-expire-an-element-in-an-array-or-sorted-set)

Instead, I just need to create a not-quite-usual queue of events to be sent to clients. This queue should:

- store events to be taken (through AJAX) into a "queue" - for this I want to use simple Redis Strings
- serve *ONLY* those events which have related time-stamp higher than one of the last request
- expire (remove) events after 1 hour from their "publishing" (because otherwise the amount of unnecessery data will be increasing into infinity, of course)

So my solution at the moment is to:

- use "namespaced" keys for Redis Strings: EVENT:{unix-time-stamp}:eventName, and value as event's content
- get all Strings (events) by key-pattern: EVENT:*
- get latest Strings (events) by *some* Redis command (which I don't know): EVENT:* WHERE "*" > given_unixtime_number

**But how to create the:**

```
"WHERE "*" > given_unixtime_number"
```

**part in Redis?**

**EDIT:**
Of course, I don't intend to stick to presented above solution. For example, I might create a separate Redis instance with non-namespaced Strings (e.g. just {unix-time-stamp} as key, without EVENT and eventName parts), if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do want to use **Sorted Sets**, and here's how:

> use "namespaced" keys for Redis Strings: EVENT:{unix-time-stamp}:eventName, and value as event's content

I'm not sure what is `eventName` is for, but this looks good enough. You can also skip the `EVENT` prefix and save 5 bytes per key. If you have a large number of events, consider using hash "buckets" as described at http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#using-hashes-to-abstract-a-very-memory-efficient-plain-key-value-store-on-top-of-redis.

> get all Strings (events) by key-pattern: EVENT:*

This is actually a crucial point - how do you do that efficiently? The answer: do not use `KEYS` or `SCAN`, instead keep an "index" of all these keys. A regular (i.e. unsorted) **Set** is good enough for these, but since you want epoch-based ordering a **Sorted Set** is the right choice.

Let's call this **Sorted Set** `events`. Whenever you create a new event, e.g. `SET EVENT:123:foo bar`, add that event's key name to the `events` using the epoch as score: `ZADD events 123 EVENT:123:foo`.

> get latest Strings (events) by some Redis command (which I don't know): EVENT:* WHERE "*" > given_unixtime_number

The command would be [`ZRANGEBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) (or [`ZREVRANGEBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore) depending on how you want the result ordered) like so: `ZRANGEBYSCORE events (given_unixtime_number +inf`. This will return all the key names that are relevant and then you'll need to `GET` them (a possible optimization is wrapping this in a Lua script to save the back and forth). Note the use of the left parenthesis (`(`) to indicate an exclusive search (i.e. `>` rather than `>=`)

**Administration:** the "cost" of this approach is that you have to maintain the `events` "index". By using the [`ZREMBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrembyscore) command on `events` you can easily remove the expired elements - call it periodically (e.g. every 1 second) or with every operation you perform according to your needs. The actual events' keys can be either `EXPIRE`d (although you may end up with expired keys in your `events` **Sorted Set** for periods of time) or `DEL`eted "manually" by adding a loop to the expiration logic that handles `events`.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds sensible to me, I'll try to implement it ASAP. However, in meanwhile I learnt also about Redis Pub/Sub solution. Do you think this Redis Pub/Sub functionality could be applied in my case?

Comment: Not with your current design - AJAX is mostly polling, right? PubSub is like broadcasting and usually not to the web client