# What are the right data-structures to model this relationship, taking advantage of TTL in Redis

Tags: database, database-design, redis, nosql

We are newbie's to redis and are trying to model the below relationship where there is a userid which could have multiple jid's and each jid will have it's own expiry time and need's to be expired at that time automatically and removed and we need to ensure that there could only be 5 jid's associated with a userid at any given point of time

```
userid1 : { jid1 : 1551140357883,
            jid2 : 1551140357882,
            jid3 : 1551140357782,
            jid4 : 1551140357782,
            jid5 : 1551140357682 }
```

From the last requirement figured that that the **sortedset** **zset** might be a good fit with name of set being the userid and field being jid and score of field being expiration time lie below

```
zadd userid1 1551140357883 jid1
```

this help us to enforce the 5 jid's per userid by checking the zset but then we are stuck on how to delete the jid's on expiry as we can't set the TTL for each element of the set. Any help in pointing us in the right direction to use the right data-structure for this use case would be great

**Note** : we may not want to introduce a batch job at this time to delete the expired tokens, **and all our queries to redis will be by userid**

Comment: possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577923/redis-possible-to-expire-an-element-in-an-array-or-sorted-set

Comment: @rainhacker i don't think its a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577923/redis-possible-to-expire-an-element-in-an-array-or-sorted-set reason being in that question the data-structure is fixed and we are trying to find a solution to that ...but in this case i'm willing to switch to any data-structure that's suggested by the community to take advantage of ttl

Comment: I get it that you want to avoid writing a batch processing mechanism to do the cleanup. But it is the recommended solution by antirez which is posted in the link shared in that answer. [Read](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/rXXMCLNkNSs) the comment where he says - "So you can have the worker purging old info every second".

Comment: You may execute `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE` before you check the size of the sorted set via `ZCARD`.