# Fetchin and Querying Sorted Sets in redis, And a solution for expiring sorted set keys

Tags: redis, ranking

I need an indexed structure in Redis.
I have a ranking algorithm and should store data with `ZADD`

```
ZADD myset 125 id::1
ZADD myset 17 id::2
```

And then, I need both the count and topmost scored data.

```
ZCOUNT myset -inf +inf
ZPOPMAX myset
```

provides what I need. But, `ZPOPMAX` not only brings topmost but also removes it.

**QUESTION 1**

I need the top most scored one, but I must NOT remove it from the sorted list.

QUESTION 2

I need to put an expiration time for each item in the sorted list. I know, expiration can be only set on keys in Redis. But I need a kind of dynamic ranking, e.g. Currently my topmost ranked data is 125, but after 12 hours, it will be 17 because the first item will be a tombstone after its TTL.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can explore the Redis commands related to `Sorted Set` **[HERE](https://redis.io/commands/#sorted_set)**

> QUESTION 1
>
> I need the top most scored one, but I must NOT remove it from the sorted list.

You can use these commands:

- `ZRANGE myset 0 0 REV` fetch the higher score
- `ZRANGE myset 0 0` fetch the lowest score.

> QUESTION 2
>
> I need to put an expiration time for each item in the sorted list. I know, expiration can be only set on keys in Redis. But I need a kind of dynamic ranking, e.g. Currently my topmost ranked data is 125, but after 12 hours, it will be 17 because the first item will be a tombstone after its TTL.

But For this, You cant use any Redis command to expire `Sorted Set` keys and I recommend using 2 separated `Sorted Set` one of them for with your regular scoring system which increase/decrease the score, and the second one same key as the first one with a time score. use a job and query keys that are outdated and remove the keys from both `Sorted Sets`.

you can query `Sorted Sets` with [`ZRANGEBYSCORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) see the [LINK](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) for the usage.

For getting more ideas on the second Question you can [READ THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577923/redis-possible-to-expire-an-element-in-an-array-or-sorted-set).