# sort keys and get 10 items after a key in redis

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I want to use Redis as like a simple database. I will need 10 items at a time for each call like pagination. When client asks for 10 items after an object, I want to get those items from Redis and If there is no specific object just want to give the latest 10.

I want to use Redis to avoid excessive usage of db reads. I will keep the objects created in the last 24 hours in Redis and serve the clients from that cache.

For the sorting and having 10 from a point problem, I thought having a sorted set and have epochs as scores and then using "zrevrangebyscore". However I see that I can not expire elements of a sorted array (since I want to have objects created in the last 24 hours). If I use seperate keys for each object, I couldn't figure out the way to sort and get a number of items starting at some point.

Do you have suggestions how to design for my case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you consider using RediSearch?

Comment: Here's [a previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577923/redis-possible-to-expire-an-element-in-an-array-or-sorted-set) with some ideas such as using a workaround (periodically deleting by score) to your current idea to get what you're looking for.

Comment: @ihsanser Would request you to reframe your problem statement. I could not at all what the requirement is.